# Exception in initializer error while run jar file

Tags: java, jar, licensing, secret-key

I am creating license for my java project using netbeans IDE.

While running a project within netbeans IDE it runs without error.

But while running jar file(build from IDE) it shows following error

> Exception in initializer error at 
>   javax.crypto.secretkeyfactory.nextspi

How to solve this error? following image shows error

[image]

Comment: Can you include the full error? It's probably because the JDK you're using in netbeans is different from the one you're using to run the jar.

Comment: Please read this and adapt your question to make it possible that someone can help you. Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You should be posting text of code or output not unreadable  cellphone pics. Either way, you can most likely fix this by installing a recent Sun JDK.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem with the JRE/JDK. Check which JRE you're using (Specifically if its Oracle or IBM) and try using the other one. The keystores created by IBM and ORACLE JREs are not compatible with each other.